# SWIFT How to make a UIButton's right side appears first then the left side

Tags: ios, swift, animation

[image]

I had made a simple UIButton animation as shown in the picture.  the left side of the Button appears first then the middle then the right. The code I have is:

```
let pulseButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("testing", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 50, width: 0, height: 28)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()

func viewComeOutFromLeft() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self. pulseButton.frame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 50, width: 80, height: 28)

    }, completion: {done in
        if done {
         print("done")
        }
    })
}
```

Now I want to make the UIButton's right side to appear first then the middle, and then the left. What should I add to the current code to make it happen?

Comment: Are you just trying to basically stretch the button out more through one animation sequence?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  self. pulseButton.frame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 50, width: -80, height: 28)
Adding a "-" to solve the issue.